# please use the the limit of difinition to prove the following:

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2+1}=1$$
I try to use the binomial theorem:
let $$\sqrt[n]{n^2+1}=1+y_n\\$$
then $$n^2+1=(1+y_n)^n$$
then $$n^2+1>1+ny_n$$
get $$y_n<n$$
based on the definition of limit,I can get
$$|\sqrt[n]{n^2+1}|<|1+y_n-1|<|y_n|<|n|<\varepsilon$$
let $$N=[\varepsilon]$$
then right here I find It doesn't work.
I don't konw where has gone wrong,or the method is not applicable to this question.
I ask for your help.

Comment: We need to show the result for all $n > N$. For $n> 2[\epsilon]$ (or more), $|n| < \epsilon$ cannot hold.

Comment: You can use squeeze theorm with $a_n=\sqrt[n]{n}$ and $b_n=\sqrt[n]{n^3}$

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq 4$ we have $$n^2+1=(1+y_n)^n=1+ny_n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}y_n^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}y_n^3+...$$$$\geq \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}y_n^3\geq \frac{(n-2)^3}{6}y_n^3$$

Now, $$y^3_n\leq 6\frac{n^2+1}{(n-2)^3}\leq\frac{12n^2}{(n-2)^3}\leq\frac{12n^2}{\big(n/2\big)^3}\leq \frac{96}{n}.$$

Hence, for given any $\epsilon>0$ we have, $$0\leq y_n\leq \frac{\sqrt[3]{96}}{\sqrt[3]{n}}<\epsilon\text{ for all }n\geq \bigg\lfloor\frac{96}{\epsilon^3}\bigg\rfloor+1$$ So, $\lim y_n=0$.